# Access key name of Object with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this array of objects:

```js
persons = [{Jon: 32}, {Paul: 35}, {Peter: 29}];
```

How can I get from the array above to the following array?

```js
persons = [
  {name: 'Jon', age: 32},
  {name: 'Paul', age: 35},
  {name: 'Peter', age: 29},
];
```

Comment: Please make an effort to accomplish your goal. Do some research on looping over an array and changing an object and try it out. If you'll get stuck, just post your code here and we'll look into it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const persons: {[key: string]: number}[] = [
           {Jon:32},
           {Paul:35},
           {Peter:29}
];

var a = persons
        .map(person => Object.keys(person)
                             .reduce(
                              (pv: {name?: string, age?: number}, cv: string) => {
                                 pv.name = cv;
                                 pv.age = person[cv];
                                 return pv;
                              },
                              {}));
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you so mush! I appreciate it!

Comment: this doesn't work in Typescript though, perhaps the tag needs removing

Answer (score 0):

Another option which looks cleaner:

```js
var persons = [{ Jon: 32 }, { Paul: 35 }, { Peter: 29 }];

var list = persons.map(p => {
  return {
    name: Object.keys(p)[0],
    age: Object.values(p)[0]
  };
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time!! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```js
var persons = [{Jon: 32}, {Paul: 35}, {Peter: 29}];
var newPersons = [];

persons.forEach(function(i){ 
    var key = Object.keys(i)[0];
    var item = {};
    item[key] = i[key]
    newPersons.push(item);
})

console.log(newPersons);
```

Answer (score 0):

Succinct Typescript version

```
const p =[{ Jon: 32 }, { Paul: 35 }, { Peter: 29 }];

console.log( p.map(x=>({ name:Object.keys(x)[0],age: Object.values(x)[0] })) )
```

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/n9zbbv-uinacj?embed=1&file=index.ts)